# What is the fastest way to get information a dependent process?

Tags: process

Currently, I am dealing with a Java program which, in some cases, starts a Python script in a subprocess and and passes a bunch of information to it via stdin, and retrieves the output via stdout. This process is not intolerably slow, but it would be a huge win if it could be made faster.

I was wondering if there were any benchmarks around using other methods of communication (sockets, perhaps?) to handle this communication.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you do some profile to see if the bottleneck is the inter-process communication? If most of the time is taken processing the data(by one of the processes), then you wont get any performance increase making the communications faster.

Comment: Well, inter-process communication and serialization are the bottleneck, but I should indeed do more benchmarking to see what the breakdown is (my guess would be serialization, but this for an analytics engine so even optimizing the IPC is worth it, if there are gains to be had there...which is what I'm probing about here :)

Comment: In your question you did not mention serialization. I thought you was simply writing some simple kind of data so that the parsing process does not take a significant amount of time. Is there any chance to reduce the amount of I/O? I mean, do you think you could avoid doing many requests and instead do some big bulk requests instead?

Comment: Bulk requests are definitely a possibility (at least as far as the IPC itself is considered). This question is not about serialization, it's about whether or not there are more efficient forms of IPC than writing to stdin.